# how to upload video file with custom metadata properties values in asset library programmatically in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When I am trying to upload document in Sp2013 asset library,I am getting System.IO.Filenot found Exception.
I have used following two approaches for adding file
1]Files.add(Filename,bytes,true); 
2]docLib.Rootfolder.files.add(Filename,bytes,true);

then I am trying to get the current item and wanted to update metadata properties by following approaches but I am getting error and If I stopped the debugging then Files get uploaded in respective document library
SpListitem item=File.item; // getting Null here
Or
I am also tryng to get unique id of the file // getting Null exception

But nothing is working for me 
NOte:I am uploading File using asp upload control through Visual Webpart

Sample of my code is as Follows:

```
                 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                 SPDocumentLibrary documentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["MyDocumentLibraryName"];
                 SPFileCollection files = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Files;
                 SPFile newFile = files.Add(documentLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/" + filename, file_bytes, true);

                 SPList documentLibraryAsList = web.Lists["MyDocumentLibraryName"];
                 SPListItem itemJustAdded = documentLibraryAsList.GetItemById(newFile.ListItemAllFields.ID); //here I have tried many approaches some I have mentioned
                 SPContentType documentContentType = documentLibraryAsList.ContentTypes["Document"]; //amend with your document-derived custom Content Type
                 itemJustAdded["ContentTypeId"] = documentContentType.Id;
                 itemJustAdded["Title"] = itemTitleText;
                 //set other propeerties here..
                 itemJustAdded.Update();
                 newFile.CheckIn("New", SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
                 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Facing issue only for Videos not for images.

Please help me I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

You need to first retrieve all the files from the folder, this video files are always stored in the so in your case.

```
var AllFolders = documentLibraryAsList.RootFolder.Folders;
```

Then iterate each file in your folder collection and get the properties you are interested in...